# i have this error when create "Grouping table head" in vxe-table v4.4.2-beta.9

Tags: vue.js, stack-overflow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RttuO.png)

### i have this error when create "Grouping table head"

`columns: [ { type: 'seq', width: 50 }, { title: '基本信息', children: [ { field: 'name', title: 'Name' }, { title: '其他信息', children: [ { field: 'nickname', title: 'Nickname' }, { field: 'age', title: 'Age', sortable: true } ] }, { field: 'sex', title: 'Sex' } ] }, { field: 'address', title: 'Address', sortable: true, showOverflow: true } ],`

## In this updated code, we have added the fixed property to the group headers